# Please add ChemJax

Tags: feature-request, support, status-completed, mathjax

Currently, [the only sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/216607/391772) with the `mhchem` extension to MathJax are Chemistry.SE, Biology.SE, EarthScienes.SE, MatterModeling.SE.

I would have liked to use ChemJax in my recent answer to: [Simulating a quantum circuit with decoherence and noise](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/23384/2293), and with there being 49 questions with the [chemistry](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chemistry) tag, it would be convenient for others too.

Adding ChemJax is very simple and comes with no disadvantages.

Comment: I'll ask around. Notice that you can already use it in answers though, you just need to include `\require{mhchem}` in some math environment before usage. I just tested it and it seems to work fine. Albeit this might load an older version, according to https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3540/15250.

Comment: User1271772 (& gIS) please note that there's a huge list of extensions offered in this answer at OR.SE: https://or.meta.stackexchange.com/a/235/51 - more than a few of which would be useful here. For example: https://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/input/tex/extensions/braket.html

Answer (score 5):

Based on your examples, I reviewed your quest, and it looks like the extension could be helpful to your site. I have enabled it for your use.

Comment: Finally!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

So, it doesn't seem like there's any significant reason not to do this, and that  there aren't performance issues to be concerned about. So I'd say maybe let's leave this up for a week or so to see if anyone has any opinion about the matter, and then tag it to have staff have a look at it and possibly implement it.